# Any problems if discriminated union has lots of options?

Tags: f#, discriminated-union

Yes, a trivial question, but I couldn't find an expert opinion on it.

I am using computation expressions to sequence server-side processes.  It helps me tremendously when my functions have the same signature, so I have a discriminated union with different combinations defined within it.  I have a couple of quick, beginners' questions.

1. Is there a recommended upper limit to the number of options that a DU can have?  Currently my DU has nine options, but this number will increase as the project progresses.  What if I hit 30 or 40 by the end of the project?
2. Might there be a problem if some of the options get "long"?  Currently, the average option has about four or five basic types--something like `bool * string * XElement * int * string`--but the longest one has the following definition:

   bool * int * int * int * string * XElement * XElement * DateTime option * DateTime option * string * Dictionary * Dictionary

I don't expect many options to be anywhere near this long.  But am I setting myself up for a world of pain in terms of performance?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There are two possible limitations here: implementation limits (does the F# language specification say anything?) or performance impact (why not give it a try: does a 1000 member DU perform slow than a 2 member DU?)

Comment: Yes, I suppose I will have to do that eventually.  But I don't know how to generate a DU with 1000 options.  (Maybe I need to read code quotations more?)  So I was wondering if someone has had an experience with the scenario.

Comment: Simple way to generate a DU with 100 options `fprintfn f "type t =";[0..100] |> List.map (fun x -> fprintf f "|T%i" x)`

Comment: @JohnPalmer, thanks a lot.  I have used the idea to generate more complex DUs to test performance.  I will post the results afterwards.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think you can safely assume that things will work well if the size of your data type is similar to the sizes of data types used by the F# compiler - the performance of the F# compiler is something that the F# team has definitely looked at and so I think they also did a few experiments to make sure the discriminated unions they use work efficiently.

- As for the number of cases, the `SynExpr` discriminated union (see [source code](https://github.com/fsharp/fsharp/blob/master/src/fsharp/ast.fs#L464)) has over 50 cases, so I think this should be fine.

  Pattern matching on discriminated union is compiled by using the `switch` IL opcode on an integer, so you can try doing some research on the efficiency of this, if you want to make sure. Also, if you just use `match` to find one specific case, then that should just be a single integer comparison, regardless of the number of other cases.
- As for the number of fields, the longest case of `SynExpr` has some 7 fields, but I suppose you can find other DUs where the length is longer. (I think a bigger problem with this number of attributes is readability - because the attributes are unnamed. So I think using a record for large number of attributes that logically belong together might be better.)

I think the size of DUs you described should be fine, but I have not done any performance testing myself - so if you really want to make sure, you need to measure it. (But as I said, I'm pretty sure this is something that has been tested as part of the F# compiler development)

Answer (score 6):

If memory serves me, I believe there were some performance issues with deeply nested pattern matches on DUs with a lot of cases / fields-per-case, but that was pre-2.0 and I believe they fixed the implementation such that currently such scenarios are well-optimized and have no glaring performance issues. (sorry, no citation).

But even when optimized, DUs de-sugar into quite a large amount of code. So even though they may perform as well (and likely better) than any equivalent hand-coded control flow, there *is* the possibility that you could stack-overflow on the sheer number of instructions emitted for a function / method body (but this would be quite an extreme scenario since the .NET default stack size is ~1MB, however, it could certainly lead to earlier than usual stack overflow in non-tail recursive method / function involving matching of the large DU, but again not likely to the degree that you should actual fear this scenario).

I don't believe it will change the performance characteristics (since we are talking about heap allocated objects in either case), but for maintainability / readability it sometimes helps to wrap your DU case data in a record type so that data fields are named and pattern matching on a subset of data fields is easier (e.g. `{Name="Stephen"}` instead of `(_,_,_,_,_,_,_,"Stephen",_,_,_,_,_)`). (@TomasPetricek beat me to this suggestion, didn't see that on my first read through his answer)

Comment: thanks a lot for the insight.  So far I have been using the hack of inserting a comment line above the DU option indicating what the variables are meant to be.  But the suggestion by you and Tomas are indeed better.